# Segmentation fault when inserting in a map

Tags: c++

I want to add a new entry in a map, but I am getting a segmentation fault message.

```
class A {

}; 

class B {
public:
    std::map<int, std::vector<A*> > m;
};

int main() {
    A *a = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A));
    B *b = (B*)malloc(sizeof(B));
    b->m[0].push_back(a);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error when I am doing b->m[0].push_back(a).

Comment: `new`, not `malloc`. This is not C.

Comment: `b->m[0]` is an attempt to use uninitialized value leading to Undefined Behavior. Note that neither `A` object or `B` objects are initialized, you've only allocated memory blocks (containing some garbage) for them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never use `malloc` in C++, always use `new`.

Because you're using `malloc` the constructor never gets called and thus your `m` is in an undefined state. Exhibiting undefined behavior when accessing it.

Moreover, `m` is storing pointers to `A`, which means that the default-constructed element when accessing with `[]` is `nullptr`, even more UB.

That said, actually never use raw `new` and just use scope based automatic lifetime or `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Actually prefer value semantics. `std::map<int, std::vector<A>>`.

Comment: @juanchopanza `B` is not empty, and it's constructor is never called, so `std::map`'s constructor is never called.

Comment: Or perhaps `std::shared_ptr` - depends on the usage